# mouseenter/mouseleave events not firing for SVG elements using jQuery.on

Tags: jquery, svg, internet-explorer-9, raphael, mouseevent

Have a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CYhgZ/72/)

The `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` don't appear to be firing correctly when using jQuery in conjuction with SVG (Raphael 2.0). I know out of the box SVG jQuery isn't 100% compatible with SVG, however, as far as I can see it only seems to effect IE9.

The weird thing is if you rapidly move your mouse on/off the svg element (making sure you come right off the HTML pane in doing so) and back onto it the events do fire (but not everytime). Just to make sure it wasn't a general problem with `on` I hooked up the `click` event which works fine, everytime.

Just wondering if anyone knows if this is a bug or even a known issue?

Comment: @StefanFandler - "*as far as I can see it only seems to affect IE9*". Tagged for clarification.

Comment: I avoid using jQuery in conjunction with SVG like the plague. It is a minefield full of exceptions like this. I think your bug is related to this http://forum.jquery.com/topic/1-6-2-broke-svg-hover-events (unsolved from two years ago).

Comment: @Duopixel yeah I seen that thread but didn't want to post a ticket until I was sure it was a definite bug and not something I was doing. In fairness for what I have needed it for, jQuery has worked pretty well with SVG. Just appears to be the mouse events it is a little unpredictable with. I will just need to revert to using Raphael instead.

Comment: You can use addEventListener, i.e http://jsfiddle.net/kGykG/ (I guess you don't need to support legacy IE because `$('circle')` wouldn't work in IE 6-8)

Comment: @Duopixel that's correct I am only supporting the latest browsers. I would like to keep my code consistent so I think for now I will revert to using Raphael. It is in fact a bug in jQuery though see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in 1.7.2. See [ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12067).

Problem goes away if I use jQuery (edge) so should be fixed in the next scheduled release (1.8).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important to note that with jQuery 1.8.2 and android via phonegap no jq-mobile used. I'm seeing touch and mouse events randomly selected and not synchronized...
meaning subtle difference trigger mouseEnter and click compared with a different touch triggering 
touchStart (sometimes if no enter even has currently been sent a mouseEnter occurs) then 2 touchEnds. 
If you had a touchEvent trigger a mouseEnter the second touch pattern (start, end, end) sends a mouseLeave (assuming you don't randomly via subtle tap differences trigger a click combo).

My expectation was they should trigger together in both situations except one (touch events) is used more for multiTouch needs, or to recognize there isn't going to be a mouseLeave event after a click event simulated through a touch interface (somehow?...).
My other expectation would be if I don't process or have a registered listener for mouse events but I do for touch events and vice versa, different events would be or wouldn't be sent depending on what listened or intercepted (return false? or to stop bubbling via preventDefault etc).

Anyway it appears to me currently you need to handle both types of events in random unconnected unpredictable ways, which for me meant discarding what in a mouse world is best described as 'over' events on touch capable devices.

Basically I'm thinking a touch shouldn't send an over/enter event, while a click should also amount to touching, and if I'm listen for touching preventDefault should cancel said mouseEvents.

Anyway it makes the most sense to send both and let me sort it out.
The confusion I suspect is in that your listening to only half the events it's sending (missing touch).
...so good luck! may those thoughts help someone deal with the mess either on the higher level or lower level dev-teams. (Is that the browser level to blame? I think so.)